# Searching for a slide with a specified tag and replacing it with a slide from a master presentation

Tags: vba, tags, powerpoint, slide

I am looking to search a presentation for a slide or slides that have a specified tag.  Once found, I would like to replace the slide with another slide from a master presentation.

I have attempted to create a solution with parts of other VBA I have collected.  I sense I am close but am not there yet (note the below gets me stuck in a loop).

Any help would be gratefully received

```
Sub ReplaceSlideThatHasTag()


For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides

'here I am selecting the slide that has the tag name "winter" and the tag id "123
If osld.Tags("WINTER") = "123" Then osld.Select

'here I am trying to add slide 27 from my master presentation immediately before the slide with the tag
ActivePresentation.Slides.InsertFromFile ("C:\my files\master presentation.PPTX"), ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex, 24, 24

'and finally I am looking to delete the slide with the tag
If osld.Tags("WINTER") = "123" Then osld.Delete


Next osld

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of general advice:  Never select anything unless you can't avoid it, and it's almost never the case that you can't avoid it.  Suggestions (with commments) below. Give this version a try.

```
Sub ReplaceSlideThatHasTag()

' ALWAYS dim your variables before using them
Dim osld as Slide

For Each osld In ActivePresentation.Slides

'here I am selecting the slide that has the tag name "winter" and the tag id "123

If osld.Tags("WINTER") = "123" Then '  DON'T select anythin osld.Select

'here I am trying to add slide 27 from my master presentation immediately before the slide with the tag
'ActivePresentation.Slides.InsertFromFile ("C:\my files\master presentation.PPTX"), 'ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex, 24, 24

' But since we're not selecting anything ...
ActivePresentation.Slides.InsertFromFile ("C:\my files\master presentation.PPTX"), _ osld.SlideIndex

'and finally I am looking to delete the slide with the tag
' But we already have a reference to the slide in the osld variable
' and we know that the slide has the tag so ...
'If osld.Tags("WINTER") = "123" Then osld.Delete
osld.Delete

' And since we've found the slide and done the deed,
' no need to continue...
Exit For
End If
Next osld

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for your advice - this is really useful.  I haven't been able to get your code working - I'm getting a 'next without for' error.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: My apologies, my bad.  I've edited the code to fix this. Just add an END IF after EXIT FOR